# Be informed of a new message - Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

I'm trying to get a push from the Gmail API when I receive a new email.

So far, the only way I've found is to do a polling every 10-15 minutes to check if there is a new unread message so I can query again to get the latest messages.

The solution I'm wishing for is a way to tell the Gmail Api to push me either the new messages that come in or an alert that there is new messages to pull.

*I initially didn't want to post my question here but the Gmail Api Support redirected me here.*

Thank you

Comment: Good question, I am looking for an answer also, because polling might not be the best approach

Comment: Try using [Push Notification](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) for Gmail API. Unlike polling that you'll send a request to Google every once in a while, whenever a mailbox changes, the Gmail API notifies your backend server application.